# Compose CIImages such that one is centered and same width above the other

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, ciimage

**I am trying to achieve this result:**
[image]

I create the gradient image which is aspect ratio 16:9.

This is my code:

```
extension UIImage {
    func mergeWithGradient(completion: @escaping (UIImage)->()){

        let width = self.size.width

        let maxWidth = min(width, 1024.0)
        let height = maxWidth * 16.0 / 9.0
        let totalSize = CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: height)

        let colors = self.colors()

    guard
        let gradientImage = UIImage(size: totalSize, gradientPoints: [(colors.top,0), (colors.bottom,1)].map{ GradientPoint(location: $0.1, color: $0.0)}),
        let cgImage = self.rotateToImageOrientationUp().cgImage,
        let cgGradientImage = gradientImage.cgImage
            else {
        return

    }
    let context = CIContext.init(options: nil)
    var ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

    let ciGradientImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgGradientImage)

    let ciMerged = ciImage.composited(over: ciGradientImage)
        let cgMerged = context.createCGImage(ciMerged, from: ciMerged.extent)!
        let uiMerged = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgMerged)


        completion(uiMerged)

    }
}
```

**But the attached code actually gets this result:**
[image]

How can I move the image to the center?
This is really easy with `CoreGraphics` but I need to do it with `CoreImage` as later on my project will need more filters and good performance.

Comment: If it's really easy with CG, why use CI? Not being critical, but sometimes you need a specific reason to go down a route - and *"...I need to do it..."* sounds vague. My first thought for using nothing but CI is to create a mask (basically make it the size of the gradient with the size of the image being the mask) and then create a (very simple) `CIKernel` that takes all three - image, gradient, mask - and outputs the appropriate pixel. I've done this and it works. But again, my **reason** for this was because the CIImages were dynamic and adjusted in real-time based on parameter changes.

Comment: Thanks. The reason is because my project will later need more image processing and require filtering and good performance. So doing it with CG doesn’t help me :)

Comment: @dfd I added the explanation in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make use Core Image to merge the images while centering the overlay, then the most straight forward way to do it is to just make your overlay image the same size as your gradient image to begin with and just letter box it with transparent pixels.  You can do it with `UIGraphicsIamgeRender` before you convert to a CIImage.

Comment: I like this idea. Combine CG and CI. I will try it out!